# How to connect 2 displays to the laptop X541U?

Tags: laptop, display, connection

I have a laptop X541U with WIN10, 64bit.
I have been told that it supports the only external display in spite that it has 2 video outputs (HDMI & VGA). The HDMI & VGA connectors are too close to each other and do not afford to connect the both cables. I tried to use the adapter USB_3_c --> VGA. Unfortunately the lap top does not support it. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lenovo Dock for this. All our clients with ThinkPad "X" machines (including myself) use the Lenovo Dock to add a monitor to their machine.

This works for us.